# How to return an array hits from msearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I've got an elasticsearch cluster I'm running a search against multiple indices (msearch) which returns an array of objects (one object for each index being queried). Each of these objects has an array of hits inside of a hits object. I'm really only after the _source object. How would you go about getting an array of all the nested "_source" objects?

```
[
  {
    "hits": {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "index1",
          "_type": "type1",
          "_id": "1",
          "_score": 12.163426,
          "_source": {
            "somekey": "some value",
            "someotherkey": "another value"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    "hits": {
      "hits": []
    },
  },
  {
    "hits": {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "index2",
          "_type": "type2",
          "_id": "2",
          "_score": 7.0380797,
          "_source": {
            "somekey": "some value",
            "someotherkey": "another value"
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "index2",
          "_type": "type2",
          "_id": "3",
          "_score": 6.07253,
          "_source": {
            "somekey": "some value 2",
            "someotherkey": "another value 2"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: `map()` over the array, down to the nested `hits.hits`, then map over that and return the nested `_source`.  And finally flatten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to traverse your outer array and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to turn `hits.hits` into array of `_source` properties as items:

```js
const src = [{"hits":{"hits":[{"_index":"index1","_type":"type1","_id":"1","_score":12.163426,"_source":{"somekey":"some value","someotherkey":"another value"}}]},},{"hits":{"hits":[]},},{"hits":{"hits":[{"_index":"index2","_type":"type2","_id":"2","_score":7.0380797,"_source":{"somekey":"some value1","someotherkey":"another value1"}},{"_index":"index2","_type":"type2","_id":"3","_score":6.07253,"_source":{"somekey":"some value 2","someotherkey":"another value 2"}}]},},],

result = src.flatMap(o => o.hits.hits.map(({_source}) => _source))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce the objects:

```js
const src = [
  {
    "hits": {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "index1",
          "_type": "type1",
          "_id": "1",
          "_score": 12.163426,
          "_source": {
            "somekey": "some value",
            "someotherkey": "another value"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    "hits": {
      "hits": []
    },
  },
  {
    "hits": {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "index2",
          "_type": "type2",
          "_id": "2",
          "_score": 7.0380797,
          "_source": {
            "somekey": "some value",
            "someotherkey": "another value"
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "index2",
          "_type": "type2",
          "_id": "3",
          "_score": 6.07253,
          "_source": {
            "somekey": "some value 2",
            "someotherkey": "another value 2"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  },
];
console.log(src.reduce((prev, el) => [...prev, ...el.hits.hits.map(o => o['_source'])], []))
```